# Do something if template type is instantiable

Tags: c++, templates, sfinae

I would like to use the SFINAE pattern to execute some code if I can instantiate a certain template class. Let's imagine this:

```
//Only instantiable with types T for which T.x() is ok:
template <class T>
class TemplateClass
{
  T t;
public:
  void foo() { 
    t.x(); 
  }
}

template <class T>
class User
{
  void foo()
  { 
    "if TemplateClass<T> is ok then do something else do nothing" 
  }
}
```

How could I do that?

Thanks a lot!

EDIT: Based on edA-qa mort-ora-y's answer I tried:

```
template <class T>
struct TemplateClass
{
    T t;
    void foo() { t.x(); }

    static const bool value = true;

};
struct A {};
struct B { void x() {} };

template <class T>
struct User
{
    template<typename M>
    typename boost::enable_if<TemplateClass<M> >::type func( ) 
    { 
        std::cout << "enabled\n";
    }

    template<typename M>
    typename boost::disable_if<TemplateClass<M> >::type func( ) 
    { 
        std::cout << "disabled\n";
    }


    void foo()
    {
        func<TemplateClass<T> >();
    }

};

User<A> a;
a.foo();

User<B> b;
b.foo();
```

But this returns "enabled enabled". What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should look at the boost [boost/utility/enable_if.hpp](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/libs/utility/enable_if.html) header and the associated meta/template programming code.

The easiest way here is to have two versions of the foo function, both template functions. One of the functions will use the enable_if construct and the other will use the disable_if construct.

I'm sure you can find better examples at the boost website, but something like this:

```
template<typename M>
typename boost::enable_if<Template<M>>::type func( ) { }
```

This function will only be defined if Template is a valid type. Since you always want to compile you'll need the counterpart, the function to call when it is not valid:

```
template<typename M>
typename boost::disable_if<Template<M>>::type func( ) { }
```

I'm not sure you can, within a single template, define two member functions in this pattern without making them both template functions. I suppose you might be able to define the two template functions and set the default template parameter to T.

I hope that helps a bit.

Comment: It compiles since Template<M> is actually valid... I'm trying to figure out now why it's valid -- if you attempt to call "foo" it fails.  I'm looking at it...

Comment: I see that I previously used the boost introspection library. If has a has_member_function construct. This is probably what you are looking for. The code is complex, why the above doesn't work is deeply related to how templates work and I don't think I'm qualified to explain it. Though I do know I have such a thing working, and the introspection examples can do what you want (but I can't remember how I found that library.)

Comment: I accepted this answer because I finally used enable_if_c with a traits class that provides the information if the type is instantiable - not by having the compiler finding it out but by defining it "manually".